# How to find out where is the baseband/radio located in MTK6582

Tags: root-access, backup, radio-firmware

I have A Micromax A120 Handset(India) 
http://www.gsmarena.com/micromax_a120_canvas_2_colors-6363.php

I want to upgrade the baseband of this phone , but before that i want to backup the current one , as i have some issues related to network on which the only option to test is to upgrade the baseband before replacing the network board.

I have gone through the internet , every where it is written in some part of adb shell you can get "by-name" to recognize which memory block it uses , but unfortunately there is no option to get it in my phone. I am giving below "cat /proc/dumchar_info" details

> shell@A120:/ $ cat /proc/dumchar_info
>
> > Part_Name Size    StartAddr   Type    MapTo

- preloader    0x0000000001400000   0x0000000000000000   2   /dev/misc-sd
- mbr          0x0000000000080000   0x0000000000000000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
- ebr1         0x0000000000080000   0x0000000000080000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
- pro_info     0x0000000000300000   0x0000000000100000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
- nvram        0x0000000000500000   0x0000000000400000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
- protect_f    0x0000000000a00000   0x0000000000900000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0p2
- protect_s    0x0000000000a00000   0x0000000001300000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0p3
- seccfg       0x0000000000020000   0x0000000001d00000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
- uboot        0x0000000000060000   0x0000000001d20000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
- bootimg      0x0000000000600000   0x0000000001d80000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
- recovery     0x0000000000600000   0x0000000002380000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
- sec_ro       0x0000000000600000   0x0000000002980000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0p4
- misc         0x0000000000080000   0x0000000002f80000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
- logo         0x0000000000300000   0x0000000003000000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
- ebr2         0x0000000000080000   0x0000000003300000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
- expdb        0x0000000000a00000   0x0000000003380000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
- android      0x0000000032000000   0x0000000003d80000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0p5
- cache        0x0000000007e00000   0x0000000035d80000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0p6
- usrdata      0x0000000040000000   0x000000003db80000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0p7
- fat          0x0000000067180000   0x000000007db80000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0p8
- bmtpool      0x0000000001500000   0x00000000febf00a8   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0

> Part_Name:Partition name you should open;
>   Size:size of partition
>   StartAddr:Start Address of partition;
>   Type:Type of partition(MTD=1,EMMC=2)
>   MapTo:actual device you operate
>   
>   can anybody help me to find out in which block the actual radio/baseband is written?

My current Baseband Version is
"MOLY.WR8.W1315.MD.WG.MP.V11.p2, 2014/02/11 18:13"

I am also looking for the latest version of this , one of my friend has my same handset but he has the latest version in it, i want to copy it
"MOLY.WR8.W1315.MD.WG.MP.V34, 2014/02/11 18:13"

Hope somebody could help me

Comment: Try this app, [Disk Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo&hl=en). It will give you all the info you need for placement of partitions. I have used it for awhile and it is just what is needed. If you have root, there are more features available. You can see temp partitions and offline ones, as well as all mounted and unmounted partitions. Good hunting.

Comment: Thank You Hash_Brown , with it could recognize my everything else except the baseband . But it helped me a lot i guess now i can analyse by eleminating the known ones in that